# org.json.JSONException: Value java.io.IOException of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

The problem is that the json is getting fetched from the url (i am saying so because the entire json content of the url is being displayed on the "logcat"), but it is somehow not geting converted to "jsonarray".

Maybe the syntax is not right or something, but i've checked everything and seems alright and still this exception is being thrown.

> SEE THE CODE and check for- JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

This line maybe the problem. "result" is a stringbuffer type which is being converted to a string in `doInBackground` function and then it is being sent to the `onPostExecute` function, where it´s being received by the `JSONArray` and then rest of the execution goes through.

But as far as I can understand the problem is the conversion of "result" to `JSONArray`. thats what the exception thrown says. 
Now i have added a line "conn.connect();" and commented "conn.DoOutput(true)". Now my entire json page is being fetched and being displayed with an alert that says-
"that the value of 'the entire of json page' of type JSONObject cannot be converted"

Load of thanks for the ones who help!!!
THis is my JSON file content-

```
     {
  "records": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "Email": "cde@algowire.com",
      "FirstName": "CDE",
      "LastName": "CDE",
      "Password": "cde",
      "Category": "Chef",
      "Descrption": "cde",
      "Tagline": "Chef LifeStyle",
      "Experience": "2 year 2 months",
      "CurrentWork": "AlgowireTechnologies",
      "Achievements": "got a prize ",
      "Hobbies": "playing,dancing etc"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "Email": "abc@algowire.com",
      "FirstName": "ABC",
      "LastName": "XYZ",
      "Password": "abc",
      "Category": "Engineer",
      "Descrption": "abc",
      "Tagline": "Engineer LifeStyle",
      "Experience": "1 year 3 months",
      "CurrentWork": "AlgowireTechnologies",
      "Achievements": "got a prize ",
      "Hobbies": "playing,dancing etc"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "Email": "demo@algowire.com",
      "FirstName": "DEMO",
      "LastName": "USER",
      "Password": "demo",
      "Category": "Doctor",
      "Descrption": "demo",
      "Tagline": "Doctor LifeStyle",
      "Experience": "2 year 5 months",
      "CurrentWork": "AlgowireTechnologies",
      "Achievements": "got a prize ",
      "Hobbies": "playing,dancing etc"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "Email": "xyz@algowire.com",
      "FirstName": "XYZ",
      "LastName": "XYZ",
      "Password": "xyz",
      "Category": "Engineer",
      "Descrption": "xyz",
      "Tagline": "Engineer LifeStyle",
      "Experience": "2 year 6 months",
      "CurrentWork": "AlgowireTechnologies",
      "Achievements": "got a prize ",
      "Hobbies": "playing,dancing etc"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "Email": "jkl@algowire.com",
      "FirstName": "JKL",
      "LastName": "JKL",
      "Password": "jkl",
      "Category": "Doctor",
      "Descrption": "jkl",
      "Tagline": "Doctor LifeStyle",
      "Experience": "2 year 4 months",
      "CurrentWork": "AlgowireTechnologies",
      "Achievements": "got a prize ",
      "Hobbies": "playing,dancing etc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Code

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            // Enter URL address where your json file resides
            // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
            url = new URL("http://192.168.1.42:81/app_data.json");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.connect();
            // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
            //conn.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return result.toString();

            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //this method will be running on UI thread

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        List<Data> data=new ArrayList<>();

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        try {

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Data fishData = new Data();
                fishData.did= json_data.getString("id");
                fishData.demail= json_data.getString("Email");
                fishData.dfirst= json_data.getString("Firstname");
                fishData.dlast= json_data.getString("Lastname");
                fishData.dpass= json_data.getString("Password");
                fishData.dcat= json_data.getString("Category");
                fishData.ddesc= json_data.getString("Description");
                fishData.dtag= json_data.getString("Tagline");
                fishData.dex= json_data.getString("Experince");
                fishData.dcurrent= json_data.getString("Currentwork");
                fishData.dachieve= json_data.getString("Achievements");
                fishData.dhobby= json_data.getString("Hobbies");
                data.add(fishData);
            }

            // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
            mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycle);
            mAdapter = new AdapterData(MainActivity.this, data);
            mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: post your json...

Comment: `return e1.toString();` is a problem. You are returning the exception.toString(), and then trying to create JSONArray from it. Check what `e.printStackTrace();` prints in logcat

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that in the catch you return the exception as the function result (`return e.toString()`).

Secondly, I think that's there is a problem in your JSON.
you can use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to check your json validation

Answer (score 0):

Please convert the result in `JSONObject`

> JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

and then try to get `JSONArray`

> JSONArray arryJ = jsonObject.getJSONArray("records");

Please check jsonObject is not null as you have all returned the error message also. You need manage error differently.

Also share you json, so we can share you the exact issue.

Updated answer ::

To avoid parsing of error you can check

```
if(jsonObject.hasKey("records")){
  //get Value of records
}
```

Comment: this won't help. Problem is very different

Comment: I don't have to. It is not my question.

Answer (score 0):

as stated by @Jay the problem was actually with the JSONArray jarray. The statement had to be preceded by a JSONObject. like-

```
            JSONObject a = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray jArray = a.getJSONArray("records");

            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

and the above code should be used when there is no name given to the array of JSON. meaning that in the above JSON, if "records" weren't there then the code in the queestion would work. meaning, this would work-

```
            //JSONObject a = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray jArray = a.getJSONArray(s);

            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

Thanks to all those who helped and tried it out!!!!

Comment: You can accept and upvote my answer. It that worked for you.